# Overlay scroll not clickable when background image attachment is fixed

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a weird issue where the overlay element is not scrollable using click and drag with the mouse , the scrollbar simply does not move. The scroll wheel seems to work fine and as intended.

I have done some debugging and found that this behaviour is caused only when the background image attachment is set to fixed however I am unable to figure out a solution.

Example code is shown below, any ideas?

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.container{
  background: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-blue-geometric-shapes-background_1035-17545.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width:100%;
  z-index:1;
}

.container-div-content{
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  height:1800px;
}
.overlay{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

}

.overlay-div{
  position:relative;
  width:90%;
  height:300px;
  z-index:1001;
  overflow:auto;
  background: white;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.overlay-div-content{
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  height:600px;
  width:60%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style media="screen">
      
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="overlay-div">
        <div class="overlay-div-content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="container-div-content"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Thanks for the edit with the snippet however the issue does not seem to present itself in the snippet.**

Comment: Your overlay is empty white and it's scrollable when I fill it with content .. what do you mean by not scrollable

Comment: There is no _"background image attachment is set to fixed"_ as you have an image in container and a overlay with fixed, but there is no link with that because they are in different element. So yeah there is no image in your overlay as it is empty anyway

Comment: Its not empty , 'overlay-div' has a child element called 'overlay-div-content' which has a height that is larger than 'overlay-div' and should activate the overflow and allow scroll functionality. Indeed the scroll is activated and the scrollbar is displayed however you can't click and drag to scroll as the bar simply does not move. This issue does not seem to replicate on the code snippet.

Comment: @MaxiGui , The background attachment causing the issue is set on the div called 'container'.

Comment: Right, I seem to have figured it out actually. When the snippet didnt cause the same issue I decided to pay a little more attention to my environment. This behaviour seems to be caused on chrome when you have 2 duplicate tabs open in Devtools mode. If one of these tabs is set to mobile , then the 2nd tab will have this weird scrolling issue. Therefore, this seems to be a chrome issue and not a code one.

Answer (score 1):

Right,
In case someone else happens to have a similar issue, this is not a code issue and is actually a Chrome bug.

**Replicating this problem**

1. Open the HTML above in Google chrome
2. Open dev tools and switch to mobile
3. Duplicate this tab
4. Exit dev tools on Tab 2
5. Now the scroll bar on Tab 2 will have this weird issue, the scrollbar is visible and you can move it using the mouse wheel however the scrollbar is not clickable and you cant click + drag it up or down.

*I was unsure whether this counted as an answer however I have posted it just in case someone else has a similar issue, if this is not an acceptable answer please go ahead and remove it.*